# Is it possible to exclude a condition, say, $f(x,y)=const.$, from a ContourPlot code?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, filtering, assumptions, conditional

```
p1 = RegionPlot[   -(3/4) <= Sin[x y] <= 1/2 , {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 4},   
FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> LightBlue];

p2=Manipulate[  Show[p1, ContourPlot[Sin[x y] + z == 1  , {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 4}, 
FrameLabel -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> Black]], {z, 0, 1}]
```

and I get

[image]

**Question:**

> Is it possible to exclude those $(x,y)$ which satisfy a general condition, say, $f(x,y)=const.$ from $p2$? In general, how we can exclude a condition (again, say, $f(x,y)=const.$) from the `ContourPlot`? for example, in the following simple code

```
ContourPlot[ Sin[x y]== 1/2 , {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 4}]
```

Comment: What is the `f[x,y]`?

Comment: @cvgmt It can be any two-variable function, say $\sin xy=\frac34$ ; I just want to know how to exclude a condition for the ContourPlot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excluded parts of a [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) are `White` so set the style of the contour to be excluded to `White`

```
p1 = RegionPlot[-(3/4) <= Sin[x y] <= 1/2,
   {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 4},
   FrameLabel -> Automatic,
   PlotStyle -> LightBlue];

p2 = Manipulate[
  Show[p1,
   ContourPlot[
    {Sin[x y] + z == 1, Sin[x y] == 1/2},
    {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 4},
    ContourStyle -> {Black,
      Switch[state,
       exclude, White,
       normal, Lighter[Blue, 0.5],
       highlight, Red]}]],
  {{state, normal, "specified contour"}, {normal, highlight, exclude},
   ControlType -> RadioButton},
  {{z, 0.2}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`Exclusions` work for some functions.

Here we exclude `y-2x==0`

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 4}, 
 Exclusions -> {y - 2 x == 0}, ContourStyle -> None, 
 Contours -> {-3/4, 1/2}, ContourShading -> {None, Blue, None}]
```

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 4}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, -3/4 <= Sin[x*y] <= 1/2], 
 Exclusions -> {y - 2 x == 0}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Blue}, #] &), ContourStyle -> None]
```

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 4}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, -3/4 <= Sin[x*y] <= 1/2], 
 Exclusions -> {y - 2 x == 0}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Blue}, #] &)]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 4}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, -3/4 <= Sin[x*y] <= 1/2], 
 Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Darker@Cyan, 
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, ViewPoint -> Top, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", Exclusions -> {y - x == 0}, 
 Axes -> {True, True, False}]
```

[image]